# Keeping shape of clip-path polygon and add a hole effect

Tags: html, css, svg

Hi I want to create a loading animation using a hole effect (I don't really know how to call it). The final goal is to hide most of the page except for the hole in the middle of the screen (which I achived on the first screenshot) so far I managed to make it work but it's not responsive at all, I used a clip-path on my background and shaped a hole in the middle like so :

```
clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 100%, 30% 100%, 50% 35%, 50% 35%, 59% 65%, 0% 65%, 30% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%)
```

Edit : To make it clearer, my first attempt used 2 elements, a div which is the black background and a svg which is the triangle in the center

[image: working effect]

[image: none responsive effect]

As you can see my pink SVG shaped triangle keeps its proportion but the background doesn't.

I found an article explaining svg Clippath and tried to use it but my shape is not centered because my svg is using path or polygon and the cx cy attributes canno't be indicated.

But is there a css attribute I'm unaware of that could hide the overlapping red triangle and black background to create a hole ? (like a reverse overflow:hidden)

[image: none centered shape]

So I tried both and couldn't find the solution, is there a way to do it like so ? Or maybe there's an another way and I haven't thought about it.

```css
#shape {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    overflow: visible;
  }

  .triangle_shape{
    fill:#894747;
  }

  .triangle {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: center;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

 

  .hide {
    z-index: 9;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #131211;
    }

    .hide_triangle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 350px;
      height: 350px;
      background-color: red;
      transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
      clip-path: url(#hidden_shape);
    }


  #loading_triangle {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 999;
    transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
    overflow: visible;
  }

  .cls-1 {
    fill:none;
    stroke:#ff3864;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke-miterlimit:10;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    stroke-dasharray: 1000;
    transform-origin: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="hide">
    <div class="hide_triangle"></div>
  </div>

  <svg id="shape" data-name="Shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 243.44 210.83" width="350px" height="350px">
    <title>hide</title>
    <clipPath id="hidden_shape">
<!--      <path class="triangle_shape" x=".5" y=".5" d="M121.89 0 0 211.12 243.77 211.12 121.89 0 0 211.12 243.77 211.12 121.89 0z" />-->
    <polygon class="triangle_shape" x="0.5" y="0.5"  points="121.89 0 0 211.12 243.77 211.12 121.89 0 0 211.12 243.77 211.12 121.89 0"/>
    </clipPath>

  </svg>

  <svg id="loading_triangle" data-name="loading triangle" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 243.44 210.83" width="350px" height="350px">
    <title>loading</title>
    <polyline class="cls-1" points="22.26 180.06 124.48 3 138.53 27.34"/>
    <polyline class="cls-1" points="143.37 35.71 246.37 214.12 211.33 214.12"/>
    <polyline class="cls-1" points="200.17 214.12 2.6 214.12 17.43 188.43"/>
    <!--    <path class="cls-1" d="M14.1 187.12 0.86 210.33 242.58 210.33 121.72 1 32.81 154.99"/>-->
  </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using 2 svg elements you can use only one where the gaps on the outer triangle are the gaps of a stroke-dasharray offseted with stroke-dashoffset.

The inner triangle is a copy of the outer one scaled down with `transform="scale(.6)"`

```css
svg{
border:1px solid;
display:block;
position:absolute;
margin: auto;
width:350px;
top:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
right:0;
}
```

```html
<svg id="shape" data-name="Shape" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="-123.24 -142  246.5 214" >
  <defs>
    <polygon id="poly" points="0 -140 121.244 70 -121.244 70 0 -140"/>
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#poly" stroke-width="3" stroke="red" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="230 12.487548828125" stroke-dashoffset="200" />
  <use xlink:href="#poly" transform="scale(.6)" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That's not what I want to achieve, it's kinda hard to explain, the final result is like my very first image I posted, the only problem I have is that the clip-path is not keeping its proportion when I change the screen size